# Show that rodriques formula is a linear transformation?

Tags: matrices

Can someone help me out on how to find the the matrix representation and show proof that it is a linear transformation?

[image]

It is the rodrigues roation formula

and the matrix representation should look like

[image]

where c and s are cos and sin

Answer (score 1):

Pick a bases for your vector space and then apply the Rodrigues formula to each of your basis vectors. The result will give you the columns of the matrix R. Normally one would pick the standard bases for such a calculation.

Alternatively you could write out the action of R on x in suffix notation, then you will be able to identify the components of the matrix quite easily.